# Algorithm to find best offer combination that gives maximum discount on a given set Of Items

Tags: algorithm

I have items with ID `(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006)`. There `respective quantities are (2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2)`: Now I have data like following.There is an offerId for each row.

```
offerId :{[Item_Id, Item_quantity_on_which_offer_Applied, Discount per quantity]}
1    :{[1001, 2, 21]}
4    :{[1002, 5, 5]} 
6    :{[1003, 1, 25] [1004, 1, 25]} 
5    :{[1004, 1, 20]} 
3    :{[1005, 5, 17.5] [1002, 5, 17.5]} 
2    :{[1005, 2, 18.33] [1001, 2, 26] [1006, 2, 21.67]}
```

**Explaination** When offer Id `1` is applied, I get Item `2` quantities of  Item Id `1002` at 21 rs. discount per quantity i.e. I am getting `21` rs. discount on `1` quantity of `1002`.

**Objective** I want to get the best offer combination. For example in above case best offer combination will be:

OfferId : 2 (discount = 132 (i.e. (18.33+26+21.67)*2))

OfferId : 3 (**note**: for 3 quantities of item `1005` and 3 quantities of item `1002` since `2` quantities of item `1005` is already in offer Id 2). (discount = 105(i.e. (17.5+17.5)*3))

Now item `1002` has `2` quantity remaining , so:

offerId : 4 (applied on `2` quantities of item `1002`)(discount = 10(i.e 5*2))

offerId : 6 (discount = (25+25)*1 = 50)

So in a nutshell, offerids 2, 3 , 4 , 6 will give me best combination of offers where offer `4` is applied on `2` quantities of item `1002`,
offer `3` for 3 quantities of item `1005` and 3 quantities of item `1002`.

Above is the result I desire to compute best offer combination depending on quantity.

So far, I had been able to find best offer combination without considering quantity. But now my requirement is to consider quantities of Items and then find best offer combination.

It would be really helpful if anyone can provide me with a pseudocode. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am writing my code in Golang but solutions in any language are welcomed.

I hope I framed my question correctly. Comment below if any more information regarding question is required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have in mind that the result set of the algorithm won't provide any information because just before black Friday, shops might enlarge prices. This might have sense if you compare the actual price with the lowest price in the internet or the second lowest if the one is the lowest.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Are the desired quantities of items given as a part of the input? Wen exactly are two offers incompatible; if and only if they have some overlap in the item type?

Comment: I have set of Items and their respective quantities. Consider that my Input is the data I have shown above. Now I have to write an algorithm in which  I can pass that data and I'll get the result  I have described.

Comment: Also, If an offer is applied on 2 quantity of a particular item, then other offer cannot be applied on that 2 quantities of that item. Suppose I have 4 quantity of  item_ id `1001`, then for 2 quantity offerId `1` can be applied and for other 2 quantity offerId `2` can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is only a single item of each type and every offer gives the same total discount (say, $1), this is **NP-hard**, since the NP-hard problem [Set Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) can be reduced to it: for each set, make an offer for the same elements with total discount $1.  Since all offers provide the same benefit, the optimal solution to this constructed instance of your problem is the one that uses the largest *number* of offers, and this solution corresponds directly to the optimal solution to the original Set Packing problem.

Thus there's no hope for a polynomial-time solution to your problem.